# How to make a for loop for some month

Tags: php, date, for-loop, pdo

I want to make for loop in php pdo that will create me an json data but loop must be for an month.

I write this:

```
 try {

       for ($i=1; $i<=30; $i++) {

    $temp = array();
    $temp['ID'] = $i; 

    $output['data'][] = $temp;
}
$jsonTable = json_encode($output);
```

SO this return me 30 rows, for 30 days. Now I want to create a range etc. to make me a rows from 01.02.2014 to rest of month 28/29.02.2014 so February ...

How to make this possible? Some ideas?

Comment: So why don't work out the number of days in the month you want, the [date()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function can do that, as can a [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object's [format()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) method

Comment: How I can see how many days have one month (etc. February) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't read the manual for yourself:

```
$dateString = '01.02.2014';
$dt = new DateTime($dateString);
$daysInMonth = $dt->format('t');
```

will give you the number of days in the month specified in `$dateString`

One way to loop through the days in a month:

```
$dateString = '01.02.2014';
$startDate = new DateTime($dateString);

$period = new DateInterval('P1M');
$endDate = clone $startDate;
$endDate->add($period);

$dayPeriod = new DateInterval('P1D');
while ($startDate < $endDate) {
    echo $startDate->format('Y-m-d'), PHP_EOL;
    $startDate->add($dayPeriod);
}
```

Another way to get that list of dates for a month

```
$dateString = '01.02.2014';
$startDate = new DateTime($dateString);

$period = new DateInterval('P1M');
$endDate = clone $startDate;
$endDate->add($period);

$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
$daterange = new DatePeriod($startDate, $interval ,$endDate);

foreach($daterange as $date){
    echo $date->format("Y-m-d") . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Explain what you mean by "dont work". Does it return an invalid value? Does it throw an error? Does it set your PC on fire?

Comment: this is also usefull: cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, 8, 2003);